# Can you verify the combinatoric recurrence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> There are $2^{10} = 1024$￼ possible 10-letter strings in which each letter is either an A or a B. Find the number of such strings that do not have more than 3 adjacent letters that are identical.

**Please confirm the recursion, and state any problems, do NOT FIX please.**

Let $F(n)$ be the $n$-lettered good sequences, let $A(n)$ be the good $n-$ lettered sequences beginning with $A$. Let $B(N)$ be the good $n$-lettered sequences beginning with $B$.

Since $F(n) = A(n) + B(n)$ I got:

$A_ _, AA, _ _, AAA _ _ _$. (Casework similar for $B$)

> $$A(n) = B(n-1) + B(n-2) + B(n-3), n\ge 4$$ $$B(n) = A(n-1) + A(n-2) + A(n-3), n \ge 4$$

**Please confirm, do not correct, and state any errors.**

I really just want to do this on my own, but the recursion is a long task. I don't want to waste time finding $F(10)$ to find the recurrence was wrong!

Thanks.

For a final answer I got:

> $548.$

Comment: Your recurrence seems fine to me.

Comment: I agree, the recurrence looks fine.  Make sure you get the initial counts right, and I don't think the recursion will take long even if you do it by hand.  Doing it in a spreadsheet would be my preference.

Comment: Define a new sequence ${C_n}$ with the property that $C_n = A_n + B_n$. Then $C_n = C_{n-1} + C_{n-2} + C_{n-3}$, and $C_1 = 2, C_2 = 4, C_3 = 8$. You can compute $C_{10}$ in closed-form (with difficulty - by putting the recurrence relationship into matrix form and diagonalising) and then $A_{10} = B_{10} = \frac{1}{2}C_{10}$ by symmetry.

Comment: @Marconius:  It's a good idea, but indeed $A_n = B_n$, so both satisfy the recurrence relation you attribute to their sum.

Comment: @hardmath - Maybe my wording was poor. I meant to say that you only need compute $C_n (=F(n))$, and if you want can find a closed-form expression for this.

Comment: @Marconius:  I was not at all disagreeing with what you stated, just suggesting a slight simplification.  You use the fact that $A_n = B_n$ at the end, so why not at the outset?